# What's wrong with my code.

Tags: java

I have this code for returning percentage of grades less than 60. But it doesn't result in the desired percent. Someone help me figure out what's wrong.

```
public float getPercentFailing(float[] grades) {

    float sum= 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < .6; i++) {
        sum = sum + grades[i];
        return sum/100;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It **will** compile, but that `.6` is still not what you want.

Comment: It does compile. I dont knw how. This is for my next basic exam practice, but its stupid, they don't give solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. You need to first add all of the grades up, which is what you're doing in the for loop. Now since we only want the grades over 60 we use an `if` statement to check if the value is above 60. If it is, add it to the sum and tally one to `int count` to keep track of how many grades we've added so far.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {      //loop through all the grades
   if(grade[i] < 60) {                         //if the grade is over 60
       sum = sum + grades[i];                  //add the grade to the sum
       count++                                 //remember how many grades so we can get average
   }
}
```

Then divide the sum of the grades by the total number of grades, or `grades.length` and `return` it.

```
return sum/count ;                             //calculate average
```

Everything together now:

```
public float getPercentFailing(float[] grades) {
    int count=0;
    float sum= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
          if(grade[i] < 60) {
             sum = sum + grades[i];
             count++
          }
    }
    return sum/count;

}
```

Comment: -1 This seems to be wrong. You're computing the average for grades less than 60%. That's not the same thing as the percentage of grades less than 60%, if I understood the OP correctly.

Comment: I see what you did, This solves, The only I had to caste sum to float. since the expected return type is a float.

Comment: @AdeqHero, NullUser is right. I believe I misunderstood the question. You are looking for the percentage of grades that fall below 60%? So five failing grades out of ten tests would be 50%.

Comment: @AdeqHero - If this is returning the correct value for your assignment, then you stated your assignment incorrectly. This does _not_ compute the "percentage of grades less than 60"; it computes the average of all the failing grades.

Comment: @TedHopp Another possibility is that the instructor carefully crafted a `grades` array such that a program like this would yield the "right" result, so he can fail students who didn't write their own tests.

Comment: @NullUserException - Heh. Yeah, I've known instructors who are that devious.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong. You want to go through all the grades and check each grade (not the loop index) against 0.6. You don't want to average the grades, you want to count how many are less than the threshold. Something like this should work:

```
public float getPercentFailing(float[] grades) {

    int failed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        if (grades[i] < 0.6) {
            failed++;
        }
    }
    return ((float) failed) / grades.length;
}
```

If you need it as a percentage instead of a fraction, change the last line to:

```
    return 100.0f * failed / grades.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop works only once, for `i=0`, since `i` is incremented as an integer from `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through all grades and count the number them which are less than 60%:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i=0; i!=grades.length; ++i) {
    if (grades[i] < 0.6) {
        count++;
    }
}

return ((float) count)/grades.length
```

Then you calculate the percentage by diving it by the total

Comment: That last line needs to use `1.0f` (or better, `((float) count)`) instead of `1.0`, since the function needs to return a `float`.

Answer (score -1):

The variable 'i' is an integer and is being used as a counter to iterate through the array 'grades'. Use the counter 'i' to index into the array to get the value of the grade, then use an if statement to check if it is a grade less than 60%. Then if it is less than 60%, add it to your total percentage and return the value as a percentage.

Extending/Editing Features code:

```
public float getPercentFailing(float[] grades) {
    int count=0;
    float sum= 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        float grade = grades[i];
        if( grade < 0.6 )
            sum = sum + grades[i];
        count++;
    }
    return sum/count;
}
```

Comment: -1 This is wrong for the same reason as Feature's answer is wrong.